# Some Huxtable functions don't seem to work for HTML output

Tags: r, huxtable

I'm learning to work with huxtables, some functions work fine when I set `output: pdf_document` but I can't get them to work work when I set the YAML settings to `output: html_document`

```
jams <- hux(
  Type = c("Strawberry", "Raspberry", "Plum", "Imaginary jam"),
  Price = c(1.90, 2.10, 1.80, "$e^{-i\\pi}$"))

jams %>%
  set_escape_contents(row = 5, 2, FALSE)
```

or

```
hux(Numbers = c(100, 3.14, 0.0002)) %>%
  set_align(-1, 1, ".")
```

Comment: can you explain what goes wrong for you? If so, you might want to file a bug.